# Common mistakes commited in saving image path to a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, web-deployment

I am working on a php project. In one of the webpage I want to keep file upload option for users. 
Here is my **user input form**

```
<?php
$db=mysqli_connect('localhost','test','test123','study')
?>
    <form form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <label for="file_array[0]">Photo :</label>   
        <input type="file" name="file_array[0]" accept=".jpeg" required />

        <input type="file" name="file_array[1]" accept=".jpeg" required />
         <label for="file_array[0]">ID Proof :</label>                
        <input type="submit" value="Upload All">

      </form>


    <?php
    if(isset($_FILES['file_array'])){
        $name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['name'];
        $tmp_name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['tmp_name'];
        $type_array = $_FILES['file_array']['type'];
        $size_array = $_FILES['file_array']['size'];
        $error_array = $_FILES['file_array']['error'];
        for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++){

            $v1=rand(1111,9999);
            $v2=rand(1111,9999);
            $v3=$v1.$v2;
            $v3=md5($v3);
            $upload_directory="uploads/";
            $TargetPath=$v3.$name_array[$i];
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], 
                $upload_directory.$TargetPath))

            {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO customers (imagepath) 
                VALUES ("$upload_directory.$TargetPath")";

        echo $name_array[$i]." upload is complete<br>";
            } 

            else {
                echo "failed to ".$name_array[$i]."
                <br>";
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

the problem is, Image gets successfully uploaded to the directory, **but** image path is not being saved into the database.
Any suggestion where I'm doing wrong in my code.

Comment: You're not actually executing the `$sql` anywhere. You're not sanitizing the input, from `$FILES` or in the `$sql`. You're mixing php and html, which in itself is not necessarily wrong but you'll hate yourself in 6 months from now.

Comment: What is the datatype of imagepath column in db. It should be text then only it will accept any no.of characters,numbers etc..

Comment: I kept it varchar with lenght of 100 @Sucharitha

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli / PDO. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. Fortunately for you, however, you never execute this query in your code, you simply define a string. You should maybe take a tutorial on how to run SQL queries in PHP

Comment: thanx @ADyson I will learn sql in more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above code your not executing the query. It is just saved in $sql. refer below code:

```
if ($db->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $db->error;
}
```

saving imagepath in db it also depends on the datatype as well.it will be text to save any length of data.